# Attach http.Server to express Route

Tags: node.js, express

Is it possible to attach a [`http.Server`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server) object as a middleware to an express [Router](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html)? I have an external library that generates a raw `http.Server`, but since I also use an express web server, I need to integrate the application logic inside of the raw `http.Server` into express. Is there a way to do what, i.e. to combine/merge the application logic from the two servers?

I've already tried the [`app.use`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.use) function, but apparently express doesn't support `http.Server`s out-of-the-box.

Comment: Speaking generally, you would need to add your express app to the HTTP server, not the other way around.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that, but I also need no do routing.

Comment: You would add the router to the app and the app to the server. This is how express works. You create an app, add routes to it, and attach it to the server. What library is generating the existing server?

Comment: The [`webtorrent`](https://webtorrent.io/) library has an option to create a [`http.Server`](https://github.com/feross/webtorrent/blob/master/docs/api.md#torrentcreateserverrequestlistener) for a torrent that is downloading, so that the user can start immediately receiving/streaming files, even before the torrent client has completed downloading all of them. I need a way to expose the files, and apply some routing beforehand.

Comment: If that's what you want to do, that's the question I would ask. I do notice from the webtorrent docs that `torrent.createServer()` accepts an optional listener as of [a recent update](https://github.com/feross/webtorrent/commit/acf3580e44ac32abe46347357ab4a261005bb14b)

Answer (score 1):

from github:

Create an http server to serve the contents of this torrent, dynamically fetching the needed torrent pieces to satisfy http requests. Range requests are supported.

**torrent.createServer([opts])**

example:

```
var client = new WebTorrent()
client.add(magnet_uri, function (torrent) {
  // create HTTP server for this torrent
  var server = torrent.createServer()
  server.listen(port) // start the server listening to a port

  // visit http://localhost:<port>/ to see a list of files

  // access individual files at http://localhost:<port>/<index> where index 
is the index
  // in the torrent.files array

  // later, cleanup...
  server.close()
  client.destroy()
})
```

Returns an http.Server instance (got from calling http.createServer). If opts is specified, it is passed to the http.createServer function.

Visiting the root of the server / will show a list of links to individual files. Access
individual files at / where  is the index in the torrent.files array
(e.g. /0, /1, etc.)

I generally use this setup together with [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors):

From the docs: "CORS is a node.js package for providing a Connect/Express middleware that can be used to enable CORS with various options."

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
var port = 3000;
var router = express.Router();

app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:4200' }));
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Node's Express is listening on Port ${port}..`));
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
const expressServer = express();

const httpServer = http.createServer();
httpServer.on("request", expressServer);
```

alternative:

```
const expressServer = express();

const httpServer = http.createServer(expressServer);
```

:-)